# Vaadin 7 Pass Data Between Views

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin7

I have two Vaadin views and i want to make a search process with these two views.
My first view contains a `TextField` for search parameter and a `Button` for seach process. What i want to do is, once user click the search button, i want to send search parameter to my second view and i will call the search method from my DAO classes here then will display the search result. I am a Vaadin newbie and i dont have any idea for how to do this so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The classic approach to pass data to a view is via the parameters of that view (this then also allows to bookmark this search). See the [View](https://vaadin.com/api/7.6.8/com/vaadin/navigator/View.html) interface:

> ```
> void enter(ViewChangeListener.ViewChangeEvent event)
> ```
>
> This view is navigated to. This method is always called before the view is shown on screen. event.getParameters() may contain extra parameters relevant to the view.

You can send those parameters from the originating view via your navigator.  E.g.

```
navigator.navigateTo("search/searchterm") 
// `search` is your view name, `searchterm` is the passed param
```

See an example in [*Handling URI Fragment Path* of the *Book of Vaadin*](https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/advanced/advanced-navigator.html#advanced.navigator.urifragment)

Answer (score 0):

I remember doing this by passing the calling View to the Subview which gets called. Try passing the calling Object to the SubView as a Constructor Parameter. Afterwards in the SubView, you can add Listeners which react on various Events you define.

Summary:
Create a View Class which implements/extends a View with your logic and a Constructor to pass that previous View(calling Object)

f.e.
In the calling class:

```
ViewX x = new ViewX(this);
```

in the SubClass

```
previousView.getDao().save(...);
```

If i would remember the Methods etc. i would have written a better example as i worked years ago with Vaadin6...